# do task A then B in gradle script

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm new to gradle script works, and hard to find at [tutorial](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorials.html) page.

In Android project, I'd like to execute `installDebug` (already defined) task then execute command-line task to launch default Activity *sequentially*.

I tried with below code but it gives error as below.

**gradle code**

```
task installAndLaunchActivity(type:Exec) {
    dependsOn("installDebug") // maybe wrong...
    def adb = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-c', 'android.intent.category.LAUNCHER', '-n', 'com.example.app/.MainActivity'
}
```

**error message**

> "Could not determine the dependencies of task
>   ':installAndLaunchActivity'.
>   Task with path 'installDebug' not found in root project 'myworks'"

Note that I'm using IntelliJ13 and `installDebug` task is successfully executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way should works:

```
task installAndLaunchActivity(type:Exec, dependsOn:"installDebug") {
    def adb = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-c', 'android.intent.category.LAUNCHER', '-n', 'com.example.app/.MainActivity'
}
```

By the way, my advice is to take a look at the [gradle-android-command-plugin](https://github.com/novoda/gradle-android-command-plugin) (use the snapshot version). It will automatically create a *runDebug* task, with proper packageName and with the proper activity to start, so you don't have to hardcode it.

Comment: Thanks. I found that IntelliJ automatically make Debug function with green bug button along with project (sometimes it's not working). Seems that IntelliJ detects `android` gradle plugin (not `android-library`) during project organazing.